# Google Charts API: more than one label rows on x axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have this chart which is a bar chart showing multiple data. The data is divided by year (2014, 2015) and quarter (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4). I can show either the quarters on the x-axis or the year, but not both. I made a screenshot and put the years in there to show what I'd like to achieve.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['bar']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
   function drawBasic() {

  //create data table object
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['','Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['Q1',1000, 400],
      ['Q2',1000, 400],
      ['Q3',1170, 460],
      ['Q4',900, 500],
      ['Q1',1400, 420],
      ['Q2',1240, 750],
      ['Q3',1001, 360],
      ['Q4',788, 800]
    ]);
  var options = {
    width: 800, height: 600, is3D: false, title: 'Company Earnings'
  };
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));

 chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
 </script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result (I added the years in paint):

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered seeing the following post sometime back that lets you add multiple x-axis details. Perhaps this will help:

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/adding-multiple-axis-labels-to-a-google-chart

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is the old style API which was deprecated. I can't find an example of this in the new one.

Comment: The other option may be to use plain old layering and relative positioning to place a label over the top...just a thought.